# Number of linearly independent sequences

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am to determine how many linearly independent $2$-element sequences are there in ${\mathbb Z^2_3}$.

I know how to show whether some set is linearly independent or not and I could probably do it for every single sequence separately but I feel there needs to be some more sophisticated way.

What if I then asked the same but for $3$-element sequences in lets say ${\mathbb Z^3_2}$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** How many ways are there to select the *first* element of the sequence? The only constraint here is that it cannot be the zero vector.

Then how many ways are there to select the *second* element of the sequence? Now the only constraint is that it cannot be one of the multiples of the first element (and the number of such multiples does not depend on which vector was chosen as the first element).

Comment: Not sure I follow. I am working with numbers $0, 1, 2$ so I should have three options to pick the first element of one sequence, right?
More specifically, all possible sequences of 2 elements should be:  
$(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(0,1),(1,0),(0,2),(2,0)$ but won't every such a sequence be their multiple in ${\mathbb Z^3_2}$ (since $0=3$, $1 =4$, etc.)?

Comment: @user293974: I understood your problem to mean that you're looking for sequences of two elements where each element is a vector in $(\mathbb Z_3)^2$. So _one_ of the sequences you're counting would be $((2,1),(0,2))$. Another possible sequence would be $((1,2),(2,1))$, but that is not linearly independent because $1\cdot (1,2)+1\cdot(2,1)=(0,0)$, which is a linear relation between the two vectors $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$.